# How to find if PHP file has constructor named the same as the class name?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I am checking PHP files to see if they have the constructor named the same as the class name. The name of the class is not known, until the word after 'class ' is captured.
EG: 'class fooBar' would have a matching 'function fooBar', however, may not be the same case, EG: 'function foobar'.
I have tried a mix of tools, and piping, but find fetching the word following 'class ' problematic when assigning to a variable, to search for 'function match.
What I have now is simply looping through all .php files, and grepping for 'class '.
The result should be a list of file paths, which have successfully matched 'class fooBar', and function fooBar.

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'class ' | awk <magic goes here>
```

Comment: If it isn't spelt the same as the class name it isn't a constructor, and named constructors are deprecated in HP anyway, for some strange reason.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a starting point at least, using any awk and assuming you want to match class-function across all files, not just within a file:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' |
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        ARGV[ARGC++] = $0
        next
    }
    { sub(/[^[:alnum:]_]+$/,"",$2) }
    $1 == "class"    { classes[$2] = FILENAME }
    $1 == "function" { functions[$2] = FILENAME }
    END {
        for ( name in classes ) {
            if ( name in functions ) {
                print name, classes[name], functions[name]
            }
        }
    }
'
```

If you really want the comparison to be case-insensitive then change:

1. `functions[$2]` to `functions[tolower($2)]`
2. `name in functions` to `tolower(name) in functions`
3. `functions[name]` to `functions[tolower(name)]`

so the comparison is case-insensitive but the output shows the original mixed-case class name.

The above assumes the names are on the same line as function or class in each input file, i.e. you never have:

```
function
foo
```

or

```
class
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use GNU `sed`, and your php files do not contain NUL characters, and the function declaration always follows the class declaration, and there are no strings, comments or other elements that could look like a class or function declaration while they are not:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec bash -c '
  sed -Enz "s!\<class\>\s+(\w+).*\<function\>\s+\1\>!$1!p" "$1"' _ {} \;
```

The trick is the `-z` option of `sed` that slurps the whole file at once and allows to search it as if it was a single line of text.